WPF Datagrid Coloring Rows and Columns
I have a DataGrid in WPF. I have to highlight a few rows so i created a RowStyle-Trigger to do this depending on a  specific property:
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding __type__}" Value="sum">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>

This works fine. Now i want to color the background of one specific column. I figured out to do this by setting the CellStyle of the DataGridTextColumn. This is the result (done with Paint):

The color of the column lays over the row-color. But i want/need it this way:

Does anybody know a way how to do this? Thanks in advance!

If you set cell style for specific column like here, then cell background is drawn on top of row background. You may need to use DataTrigger to color cell (or not) to achieve needed (example), not sure how exactly, maybe by looking up in visual tree if row background is {x:Null} or not?

Thanks a lot for your comment. After reading the answers i think it would by useful if i manage to overwrite/delete the CellStyle of the column in the yellow rows.
